# How to run Parity on Windows correctly?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

Installed Parity 1.11.7 from the [official website](http://parity.io) on Windows 10, then synced it, got the expected result:

[image: synced Parity works as expected]
Then rebooted the PC, tried to launch Parity using the shortcut in Start menu (which points to `C:\Program Files\Parity Technologies\Parity\ptray.exe`), got this:

[image: THE PARITY UI HAS BEEN SPLIT OFF INTO A STANDALONE PROJECT. GET THE STANDALONE PARITY UI FROM HERE]

Error message

```
THE PARITY UI HAS BEEN SPLIT OFF INTO A STANDALONE PROJECT.
GET THE STANDALONE PARITY UI FROM HERE
```

Tries to force me to install something from

https://github.com/Parity-JS/shell/releases

but I obviously want just to move things back to the state before the reboot.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Killing Parity process and starting it again helps.